# Undo/Redoing adjustments to whole image (Android)

Tags: android, image-processing, processing, undo

**Note:**

Please bear with me, this (imho) is not a duplicate of the dozen questions asking about undoing in paint/draw scenarios.

**Background:**

I've been developing an image processing application, using Processing for Android and now I'm trying to implement a simple, one-step undo/redo functionality.

My initial (undo-friendly) idea was to apply the adjustments to the downsampled preview image only, keep an array of adjustment actions, and apply them at save-time to the original image. I had to sack this idea for two reasons:

- some of the actions take a few seconds to finish, and if we have a few of these, it will make the already slow saving process tediously slower.
- some actions (e.g. color-noise reduction) produce drastically different (wrong) results when applied to the downsampled image instead of the full-sized image. But anyways this is a less serious problem...

So I decided to go with storing the before/after images.

**Problem:**

Unfortunately buffering the images in memory is not an option because of memory limitations. So what I'm doing at the moment is saving the before/after images to internal storage.

But that creates a performance/quality dilemma:

- **jpeg** is fast (i.e. ~500ms to save on my Xperia Arc S) but degrades the quality beyond acceptability after two/three iterations.
- **png** is of course lossless, but is super slow (~7000ms to save) which makes it impractical.
- **bmp** I guess would probably be fast, but android does not encode bmp (I think processing for android saves "file.bmp" as tiff).
- **tiff** has somewhat acceptable performance (~1500ms to save), but android does not decode tiff.
- I also tried writing the **raw** pixel array to a file using this function:

  ```
  void writeData(String filename, int[] data) {
    try {
      DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dos.writeInt(data[i]);
      }
      dos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  ```

  but it takes above 2000ms to finish, so I gave up on it for now.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a faster way of writing/reading the data for this purpose?
2. ...or should I go back to the initial idea and try to solve its problems as much as possible?
3. Any other suggestions?

**Update:**

I came up with this method to write the raw data:

```
void saveRAW2(String filename) {
  byte[] bytes = new byte[orig.pixels.length*3];
  orig.loadPixels(); //orig = my original PImage, duh!
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i++] = (byte)((orig.pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xff);
    bytes[i++] = (byte)((orig.pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xff);
    bytes[i] = (byte)((orig.pixels[index]) & 0xff);
    index++;
  }
  saveBytes(filename, bytes);
}
```

...and it takes less than 1000ms to finish.

It runs 3 times faster than that if I write the file on my SD card, but I guess I can't count on that to be the same on every phone. right?

Anyways, I'm using this method to read the saved data back into orig.pixels:

```
void loadRAW(String filename) {
  byte[] bytes = loadBytes(filename);
  int index = 0;
  int count = bytes.length/3;
  for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
    orig.pixels[i] = 
      0xFF000000 |
      (bytes[index++] & 0xff) << 16 |
      (bytes[index++] & 0xff) << 8 |
      (bytes[index++] & 0xff);
  }
  orig.updatePixels();
}
```

This takes ~1500ms to finish. Any ideas for optimizing that?

Comment: why is memory a constraint? how big are you allowing images to be? Are you using tiling, or are these naive operations (i.e. applied to the entire image). Additional note: you're using plain Java as part of your Processing application, raising the question why you're using Processing rather than using Java with Processing for some of the draw functions (but NOT for your actual imaging algorithms)

Comment: @Pomax, the images are around 1600x1200, depending on the device (incrementally downsampling images till it does not throw OOM). This combined with other stuff in the memory easily hits the 16MB limit on older devices. I'm not using tiling.

Comment: @Pomax again! 
I'm not really a programmer and only had experience in processing, wanted to give processing for android a try. Little by little I had to give up on most of processing methods and implement mine using plain java... but then I had gone too deep to start from scratch without processing. :) Anyways I thought if I can still achieve acceptable performance with  this, why not fully develop the app?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend finding out what the Android "scratch disk" area is, and processing your images as tiles, caching them on that scratch disk. This might be a bit slower than straight memory use, but it means you can do your image editing without running into memory limitations, and (provided Android's SDK has a sensible API), writing the tiles to a full file shouldn't take incredibly long. That said, you've kind of moved from "Processing" to plain Java, so the question isn't really about Processing anymore... and my answer is probably not as good as someone who's intimately familiar with the Android SDK

Comment: But is that different from what I've already described I'm doing above?... except the tile thing of course. I've managed to avoid OOM on image edits and my images are not super big. So I guess I won't need to go through the troubles of tiling (I have operations which include blurring etc.). and since you're also suggesting caching to disk, which is what I'm doing, I won't be needing any more memory too. or am I missing something?

Comment: to be more specific, I've already described the same thing in my "update:" above (except tiling of course) i.e. caching to internal memroy/cache folder (scratch disk). Can you tell me if there's a faster method of reading the cached file than what I'm already doing?

Comment: I can't, I have literally zero knowledge of the restrictions imposed by Android, and the API calls that effect quick disk writes of images.